# asp.net core 2.0 windows role based authorization always returns 403

Tags: windows, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-authorization

I'm trying to setup up role based authorization based on Windows roles using an asp.net core 2.0 app. This is the configuration:

launchSettings.json:

```
   {
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:9180/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Bouwfonds.Gems.Onderhoud.Web.UI": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:9181/"
    }
  }
}
```

StartUp.cs:

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

  }
```

and in the controller:

//SID of Administrators using: psgetsid.exe Administrators

```
  [Authorize(Roles = @"S-1-5-32-544")] 
  public class HomeController : Controller
```

The Windows authentication is working but I always get back a 403. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The local administrators group is added as a denyonlysid(?) claim: "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/denyonlysid: S-1-5-32-544}" so I guess that's why that group doesn't work. And obviously when u add yourself to a new local group u have to reboot before u get the claim :P

So it now works with a local group even without the SID but just the group name.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I got to work.  A lot of it I pieced together using the Microsoft Authorization Workshop example https://github.com/blowdart/AspNetAuthorizationWorkshop.  Although I am using policies instead of roles.

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
         //Add policies as needed along with authorization classes
         options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new AdminAuthorization()));
    });

    services.AddMvc(config => 
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    });

    //Also add the Authorization Handlers
    services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, AdminAuthorization>();

    serviecs.AddAuthentication(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}
```

AdminAuthorization.cs

```
public class AdminAuthorization : AuthorizationHandler<AdminAuthorization>, IAuthorizationRequirement
{
     protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthrizationHandlerContext context, AdminAuthorization  requirement)
     {
         if(context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Value == @"S-1-5-32-544"))
         {
             context.Succeed(requirement);
         }
         else 
         {
             context.Fail();
         }
         return Task.CompletedTask;
     }
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
//Add the name of the policy used in the options.AddPolicy in the startup.cs
[Authorize(Policy = "Admin")] 
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // your controller logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A 403 response generally indicates one of two conditions:

- Authentication was provided, but the authenticated user is not permitted to perform the requested operation.
- The operation is forbidden to all users. For example, requests for a directory listing return code 403 when directory listing has been disabled.

Are you sure, that you are in the given group? First try to authorize a user, not role:

```
[Authorize(Users="Alice, Bob, YourName")]
```

If this works, then you either are not a member of the group or the group does not exist.

Comment: The Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizeAttribute has no Users property, but yes I'm sure I have that role. I also tried a new local group so u can just say "DESKTOP-V3136HA\RoleName" but with the same result.

Comment: Are you able to look at the `HttpContext.Request.User.Identities` to see if the middleware is adding the IIS User?